# Wait for keyboard available command

Tags: linux, busybox, input

I have sh script, which autorun app on boot. I need to ensure, that keyboard is logged in system before app start. Will be nice to see solution for mouse too.

I use embedded system created with Buildroot with Busybox Init.

EDIT: The best working solution that I find is searching for device files, but I don't know If it is fastest solution:

```
while ! [[ "$(ls /dev/input/by-path/*-kbd)" ]]; do usleep 1000; done
```

Answer (score 1):

In your embedded system, you've included `udev` I presume?
And your keyboard/mouse are all plugged in before you start boot?
If so, then the command `udevadm settle` will accomplish what you're asking for.

Comment: I don't know why, but it don't works. I can't use keyboard in my app runned after this command. Seems to be that my app is runned too fast after boot.